# MS Flow and SharePoint Connections limitation

Tags: sharepoint-online, error, power-automate, microsoft-flow, connection

I have a couple of active MS flows for SharePoint.

Today while creating a new flow I got the error "Request to XRM API failed with error:

> 'Message: Connection reference 'new_sharedsharepointonline_a9cda' is already associated to '16' flows. Please create a new connection reference to use on this flow. Code: 0x80040216 InnerError:'.

Can anyone guide me what is the solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, while connection references are in preview, one connection reference can only be used within a maximum of 16 flows.

If the same connection needs to be used in more than 16 flows, then create another connection reference with a connection to the same connector. There is no limit to the number of actions in each flow that can be associated with the connection reference.

Reference:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/common-data-service/create-connection-reference

Answer (score 1):

This is not an error but a limitation for using same connection across multiple flows.
One single connection can be referenced in 16 flows only, which means if i create a connection SharePoint Connection using adb@xyz.onmicrosft.com it can be used in 16 flows. If i create 17th flow and try using this connection it won't allow you to use it. To fix this go to connections and create a duplicate connection and use it in your flow.